# Bulk processing in mongo is very slow for 1 million records

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Consider the following scenario:

CSV file is generated by a reporting tool every friday. It contains records for all the employees in the organisation (almost 1 million employees and increasing).

This data is saved in mongo using mongoimport in "Employee" Collection.

However, the requirement is to send "Welcome Mail" to new employees and "Year Completion Mail" to existing employees.

To solve this, I am importing the new file to a temporary collection("EmployeeTemp").

For every record in the temporary collection (EmployeeTemp), I check the old collection ("Employee"), for existing employees and mark "SendYearCompletionFlag" as true. Further, if a new employee record is found, I mark "SendWelcomeFlag" as true. Also, the project of each employee needs to be updated.

This complete process is executed via a script submitted to mongo.

The issue is that script is taking almost 18 hrs to complete.

Please help me to reduce the execution time of script.

This the script:

```js
var list = db.employeeTemp.find().addOption(DBQuery.Option.noTimeout);
while(list.hasNext()){
    var f = list.next();
    var itr = db.employee.find({"eid":f.eid});
    var obj = itr.hasNext() ? itr.next() : null;
    if(!obj){
        f.joiningDate = new Date();
        f.sendWelcomeMail = true; 
        print("Saving New record : " + f.eid);
        db.save(f);
    } else {
        var joinDate = obj.joiningDate;     
        if(new Date().getTime()-joinDate>=31536000000){
            print("Sending Year Completion Mail to " + obj.eid)
            obj.sendYearCompletionMail = true;
        }
        obj.projecct = f.project;
        print("Saving Existing record : " + obj.eid);
        db.save(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try reading the site guidelines on posting. That is not how you post code.

Comment: The only thing comes to my mind is: define index for employee.eid, and you can use findOne() instead of find()

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create an index on employee.eid.

Another thing you can try is to change the batch size in the first find adding batchSize(500) after setting the no timeout option:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/

Comment: Good to note that batchsize respects size before number, so if 500 is more than a BSON documents max size (I think batch might be configured with a max size of 4mb atm) then it will go by that first and not the 500

Comment: 500 was an example. Of course he must verify which is the optimal batch size for its application. In its case, as MongoDB returns a cursor, the application will be querying the server for more documents about 500.000 times (20 is the default batch size I think). If he increases the batch size there will be less communications between the application and the server.